# How to execute  CGI through HTML's HREF link

Tags: html, perl, cgi, web

I want to create a HTML link. Such that when a link is clicked 
a CGI-script will be executed instead. That CGI script will take
a parameter also.

I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
<a href="./cgi-bin/run_script.cgi $param">Query</a>
```

Is there a right way to do it?

What I'm trying to do is to have a page that contain many words.
When a word is clicked, a CGI script will be executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way would be:

```
<a href="./cgi-bin/run_script.cgi?param=value">Query</a>
```

To fetch the value of the parameter in your Perl script:

```
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $param = $cgi->param('param');
```

Answer (score -2):

Using the POST or GET method:

http://www.scs.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/Cgi/textareas.html

Comment: I'm aware of form. I don't want to use form to do that purpose. See update on the reasoning.

Comment: @neversaint: Please don't link to that tutorial. The front page (http://www.scs.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/) clearly labels it as a Perl _4_ tutorial that was written 20 years ago. People reading that tutorial will learn many outdated practices.